# Modifying a data file: issue with savetxt header option

Tags: python, numpy

I have a bunch of files from a LAMMPS simulation made by a 9-lines header and a Nx5 data array (N is large, order 10000). A file looks like this:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
1700000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
40900
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0 59.39
0 59.39
0 59.39
ITEM: ATOMS id type xu yu zu 
1 1 -68.737755560980844 1.190046376093027 122.754819323806714 
2 1 -68.334493269859621 0.365731265115530 122.943111038981527 
3 1 -68.413018326512173 -0.456802254452782 123.436843456292138 
4 1 -68.821350328206080 -1.360098170077123 123.314784135612115 
5 1 -67.876948635447775 -1.533699833382506 123.072964235308660 
6 1 -67.062910322675322 -2.006415676993953 123.431518511867381 
7 1 -67.069984116148134 -2.899068427170739 123.057125785834685 
8 1 -66.207325578729183 -3.292545155979909 123.377770523297343 
...
```

I would like to open every file, perform a certain operation on the numerical data and save the file with a different name leaving the header unchanged. My script is:

```
for f in files:
filename=path+"/"+f
with open(filename) as myfile:
        header = ' '.join([next(myfile) for x in xrange(9)]) 
data=np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=9)
data[:,2:5]%=L #Put everything inside the box...
savetxt(filename.replace("lammpstrj","fold.lammpstrj"),data,header=header,comments="",fmt="%d %d %.15f %.15f %.15f")
```

The output, though, looks like this:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
 1700000
 ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
 40900
 ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
 0 59.39
 0 59.39
 0 59.39
 ITEM: ATOMS id type xu yu zu 

1 1 50.042244439019157 1.190046376093027 3.974819323806713
2 1 50.445506730140380 0.365731265115530 4.163111038981526
3 1 50.366981673487828 58.933197745547218 4.656843456292137
4 1 49.958649671793921 58.029901829922878 4.534784135612114
5 1 50.903051364552226 57.856300166617494 4.292964235308659
6 1 51.717089677324680 57.383584323006048 4.651518511867380
7 1 51.710015883851867 56.490931572829261 4.277125785834684
8 1 52.572674421270818 56.097454844020092 4.597770523297342
...
```

The header is not exactly the same: there are spaces at the beginning of every lines except for the first, and a newline after the last line of the header. I need to get rid of those, but I don't know how.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in `' '.join()`, why are you joining them with a space character, rather than empty `''`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the `' '.join(a)`:

```
a = ['sadf\n', 'sdfg\n']
' '.join(a)
 >>>'sadf\n sdfg\n' # Note the space at the start of the second line.
```

Instead:

```
''.join(a)
>>>'sadf\nsdfg\n'
```

You will also need to trim the last '\n' in your header to prevent the empty line:

```
''.join(a).rstrip()
>>>'sadf\nsdfg'
```

Comment: Nice, this rstrip() function is useful indeed. This is the first time I use it.

Answer (score 0):

The header parameter will add a newline after it automatically, so you can eliminate the original last '\n' as a redundant newline.

```
header = header.rstrip('\n')
```

The leading spaces occurs, since you join each line by an extra space character. you can solve it by the below command.

```
header = ''.join([next(myfile) for x in xrange(9)])
```